# white text and black background using xml code android

Tags: android, html, xml, graphics, calculator

How to fill the background efficiently with white text and black background.when i fill the backgound using this code in xml in Button filed

```
        android:background="#c6010101"
```

Button code is here

```
     <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/OpenBraces"
        android:id="@+id/buttonOB"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
        android:background="#c6010101"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC" />
```

Full code is here.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:digits="0123456789=+-*^/{}.xX"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<!-- Footer Ends -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/One"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#64010001"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC"  />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Two"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
        android:background="#64010001"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Three"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        android:background="#64010001"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Plus"
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        android:backgroundTint="#c6010101"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Four"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button8"
        android:background="#64010001"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Five"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
        android:background="#64010001"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Six"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
        android:background="#64010001"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Minus"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
        android:backgroundTint="#c6010101"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Seven"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button8"
        android:background="#64010001"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Eight"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button5"
        android:background="#64010001"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Nine"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button8"
        android:background="#64010001"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Multiply"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMul"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button9"
        android:backgroundTint="#c6010101"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Dot"
        android:id="@+id/buttonDot"
        android:background="#64010001"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button8" />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Zero"
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button8"
        android:background="#64010001"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Equal"
        android:id="@+id/buttonEqual"
        android:backgroundTint="#c6010101"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Divide"
        android:id="@+id/buttonDiv"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button9"
        android:backgroundTint="#c6010101"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/VariableX"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/buttonVarX"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        android:backgroundTint="#c6010101"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC" />


    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/OpenBraces"
        android:id="@+id/buttonOB"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
        android:background="#c6010101"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/CloseBraces"
        android:id="@+id/buttonCB"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button3"
        android:backgroundTint="#c6010101"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Power"
        android:id="@+id/buttonPow"
        android:backgroundTint="#c6010101"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFCFC"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonPlus"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonBS"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_rew"
    android:background="#c6010101"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Back"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout0"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/webView" />

<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonBS" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/buttonSolution"
    android:id="@+id/buttonSol"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout0"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

then it android:background not only fill the button area but also fills the outer area of the button. At this area the button click is not working because it is not part of the Button but it looks like as it is part of the button as you can see in this pic

[image: Button outer area fill with color]

The empty space out side of the button is shown in this picture. i want to show it with this shape with white text and black button color.

[image: outer area not fill]

i have also try to use android:backgroundTint="#c6010101" it shows in android as i want but it does not work on mobile.

Comment: please add entire xml layout as well for better understanding.

Comment: now full code has been written

Answer (score 0):

it can be resolved by giving the shape. we can do it by using the select

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_1_selected"
android:state_pressed="true"/>
<!-- focused state -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_1_focused"
android:state_focused="true"/>
<!-- default state -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_1_normal"/>
</selector>
```

write this code and save with extension .xml (btn_black.xml) in drawable folder of E:\My-Application\app\src\main\res\drawable

and in your button xml code add this code

also write the code of focused, normal and selected in xml and save in the same folder(drawable) with the the name as you have given in the selector code. in this code file name will be

```
button_1_focused.xml
button_1_normal.xml
button_1_selected.xml
```

button_1_normal.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/button_1_normal_background"/>
<corners android:radius="10dip"/>
 </shape>
```

similer for other . 
Also see this side http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1006843/An-Efficient-Way-to-Make-Button-Color-Change-on-An